# Using scrbook, how to suppress page numbers for all but several chapters in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, scrbook

I want to publish a book, and our publishing center style guide suggests the following style rules for the table of contents:

1. Every book chapter and section must have its entry in TOC.
2. If a book chapter doesn't have any sections, then it must have its page number in TOC, preceded by dots,
3. If a book chapter has nested sections, then only its name without page number must be present in TOC.

So I would like to suppress page numbers for numbered chapters, and show them only for unnumbered chapters, such as Introduction and Conclusion.

The MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 
               fontsize=14pt, 
               DIV=calc,
               twoside=false,
               headings=small,
               numbers=endperiod,
               chapterentrydots=true,
               ]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\newpage
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter without page number}
\section{Section One}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

With KOMA version 3.20 (or newer) it is possible to define an own tocentry style for unnumbered chapters. So here is a new suggestion to suppress the page numbers of all numbered chapters and to insert a dotted line for the unnumbered chapter entries in TOC.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 
               fontsize=14pt, 
               DIV=calc,
               twoside=false,
               headings=small,
               numbers=endperiod,
               ]{scrbook}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocpagenumberbox=\blankbox
]{chapter}
\newcommand\blankbox[1]{}% do nothing

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=1.5em,
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{chapter}{unnumberedchapter}
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@unnumberedchapter{\chaptertocdepth}% needed if hyperref is used
\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
  {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
  {\IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocentrydefault{unnumberedchapter}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section One}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

With a KOMA-Script class you can use

```
\addchap{Introduction}
```

instead `\chapter*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}`.

Here is a suggestion to suppress page numbers of *all* numbered chapters in TOC:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 
               fontsize=14pt, 
               DIV=calc,
               twoside=false,
               headings=small,
               numbers=endperiod,
               ]{scrbook}

\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}

\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocontents{toc}
        {\protect\begingroup
          \protect\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{}%
          \protect\KOMAoptions{chapterentrydots}%
        }%
      \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}%
    }
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter without page number}
\section{Section One}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, miktex complains about undefined control sequence: `! Undefined control sequence.
\addchaptertocentry #1#2->\IfArgIsEmpty {#1} {\addtocontents {toc}{\protect...
l.26 \addchap{Introduction}
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.` Otherwise your TOC looks just great, thank you.

Comment: I tried it with TexLive on Linux, and it worked wonderfully! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you have to update your MiKTeX packages. Current KOMA Script Version in both MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXLive 2015 ist 3.19a. But you can replace `\IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{...}{...}` by `\ifstr{#1}{}{...}{...}`.

Comment: MikTex 2.9 Package Manager shows me 3.15 as the latest version available, so I had to update it manually. Meanwhile I got one more question: if I try to import `color` or `xcolor` package, everything breaks down. Maybe you know why?

Comment: I found a workaround by removing everything connected with `pdfcolorstack` from `.toc` file manually, but if there is a way to do this automatically, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Ok, never mind, I figured it out. The problem was in `\usekomafont`, which returned a bunch of stuff related to font coloring. I changed it to `\sffamily \bfseries`, and everything worked out quite nicely.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a `\protect` before `\usekomafont{disposition}`. But I have changed my answer: with `\protect\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{}` the chapter page number gets in TOC the same font as the `chapterentry`.