# Contents page - include roman numeral page numbers

Tags: sectioning

I am using MiKTex 2.9. I would like to include the 'Abbreviations' page in my contents page, along with the roman numeral page number. However when I use the `\section{section name}`command it gives the title a section number. And when I use `\section*{section name}`, the title does not appear in the contents page. I have also tried the suggestion from [Using scrbook, how to suppress page numbers for all but several chapters in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281114/using-scrbook-how-to-suppress-page-numbers-for-all-but-several-chapters-in-toc) but I get an 'undefined control error'.

Can you please advise? I have attached my MWE.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage,caption}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section*{Abbreviations}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{60pt}
\centering
  \small
 % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
{Abbreviation}&{Explanation}\\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
Item1&Item1\\
\bottomrule
 \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\label{table:ETD Raman}
\end{table}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Test 1}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using a `table` environment is wrong here, remove it. Also, ***Always*** do `\cleardoublepage` before changing the pagenumbering style. Also, package `times`  is obsolete for many years, just to point out a few things in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard LaTeX command `\addcontentsline{<file>}{<kind>}{<text>}` immediately after your `\section*{Abbreviations}` as:

```
\section*{Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations}
```

which will put an unnumbered section style heading and page number into the `.toc` file for printing in the ToC.

Comment: this will work if the abbreviations list is less than a page, but if it's longer than a page, the page number in the toc will be wrong.  in that case, since `\newoage` immediately precedes `\section*{Abbreviations}`, the `\addcontentsline` cam be moved up to precede the `\section*` line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton. My table is greater than a page but your suggestion does not seem to work. The order that I currently have (from top to bottom of page) is: '\newpage' ,
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations} , \section*{Abbreviations}. Any advice you can give would be great.

Comment: @Kevin -- after looking more closely at the structure of your example, it is clear that this answer will work as advertised.  (there are circumstances where my suggestion *is* more reliable.  however, using the example as you have framed it, either order works.  so there must be something else affecting your real file.  remember that you have to process the file twice to add an entry to the toc.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton When is your suggestion more reliable? My understanding is that a `\section` command might start a new page before the title but will not immediately start one after the title, so a following `\addcontentsline` will use the page number of the section's title.

Comment: @Kevin Did my answer work for you? If not please give a MWE showing the failure.

Comment: @PeterWilson -- if `\section*` is the first line on the page, then your code should *always* work.  what i was thinking of was an environment that could begin with a section heading (like a list of figures) over which one has no control of the environment definition.  it's often suggested that `\sddcontentsline` be added after the environment-calling command, but then the page number will be wrong if the contents of that environment runs to more than one page.  (apologies for the confusion.)

Comment: I tried both suggestions but no success. Testing on a new document, however, does work. Therefore there must be a conflicting package/code in my document. To solve the problem, I used \longtable instead of \tabular, incorporating your suggestions and that did the trick. Thanks!