# book, tocloft - How to suppress page numbers for all but several chapters in ToC?

Tags: tocloft, books

This question is the equivalent to [Using scrbook, how to suppress page numbers for all but several chapters in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281114/using-scrbook-how-to-suppress-page-numbers-for-all-but-several-chapters-in-toc), but refers to the `book` document class.

The question is, how to suppress page numbers for certain chapters in ToC? Using package `tocloft` one can call `\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}`, but this command will suppress page number for *every* chapter.

A solution to this question would be useful for typesetting the table of contents when chapters do not bear significant text after the title, but only introduce sections (say).

The soultion should possibly work selectively for different parts of the book if needed, and should be compatible with "modified" scopes, such as appendices.

[image]

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter with page number}

\chapter{Chapter that should have no page number}
\section{First section}

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix (with or w/o p. number)}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible adding the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
```

just before opening the chapter, as in the MWE below, where the page number whas then reactived (`\cftpagenumberson`). [see the [tocloft manual](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf), p. 12]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter with page number}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\chapter{Chapter that should have no page number}

\section{First section}

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix (with or w/o p. number)}

\end{document}
```

[image]